# Converting img file to FAT32

Tags: command-line, fat32

I'm trying to make convert an img file to FAT32.

Here is the code I execute:

```
sudo dd if=/dev/zero of=./testImage bs=10000000 count=1
```

Then the output I get is:

```
1+0 records in
1+0 records out
10000000 bytes (10 MB) copied, 0.0609494 s, 164 MB/s
```

Then if I do this code:

```
sudo mkfs.vfat -F 32 ./testImage
```

Then the output I get is:

```
mkfs.vfat 3.0.12 (29 Oct 2011)
WARNING: Not enough clusters for a 32 bit FAT!
```

I am trying to debug my code but I can't create a FAT file to debug...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

10 MB is not big enough for FAT32. Typical use cases for FAT32 are disks larger than 512 MiB, below that usually FAT16 is used.

It seems that the minimum size is somewhere around 33 MiB:

```
$ dd if=/dev/zero of=./testImage bs=1M count=33
33+0 records in
33+0 records out
34603008 bytes (35 MB) copied, 0.0230871 s, 1.5 GB/s
$ mkfs.vfat -F 32 -v ./testImage
$
```

---

By the way, you do not need to use `sudo` for any of these commands if your user has permissions to create files in the current directory (`.`)

Answer (score 1):

After a lot of googling, I found an answer to your problem. 
Your code

```
mkfs.vfat -F 32 ./testImage
```

You need to specify cluster size.

`mkfs.vfat -s 16 -F 32 ./testImage`

Hope it helps.